# EE1 using a port different than 80. How can I make it?

Tags: ee1, install

I need to setup a EE1 but using a different port. It cant be 80 since th server is a asp server using regular port (80) for the main site, but it has PHP in a different port.
Is there any place where I can specify which port EE1 must use??

Comment: Think this question is better off asked at ServerVault: http://serverfault.com/

Comment: What do you mean by "EE1 use different port"? You have something like *example.com:9999/* ?
If yes - did you try to replace  *URL to the root directory of your site* in *General Configuration*?

Comment: Hi Max! Thanks for your reply. Yes I have that example. The server works with php using a specific port, just like you said, example.com:9999. Didnt try what you say, will see. I guess in my local env, it should be example.loc:80 since it  is installed by default

Comment: Hi @maxLazar! I tried adding the port to the main URL but nothing changed, even I tried using any number as port and nothing. I mean, all works fine always so adding the port there makes no difference. I was thinking on the htaccess
How could I make to point all the requests to a specific port there?
I tried this:
'RewriteRule (.*) http://testsite.loc:80/$1 [R=301,L]' 
But it made an infinite loop
Any idea??
thanks in advance!